# Click inside <iframe> doesn't work properly using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am trying to click some link inside a iframe using selenium webdriver.
I came across a weird problem.
The click only works when whole iframe is visible.
So i tried clicking when my iframe was partially visible and the link i wanted to click inside i frame was visible, but click doesn't happen and code executes successfully.
I tried checking all web elements and it is fetching all web elements correctly.

I want to click certain link inside the iframe.

Comment: Please also provide the website or sourcecode you use, the specific button otr element you want to click on and the code you used

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Pls share a relevant html source and the code which you tried..